# Get video file name after saving

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I use the code below to save the video and it's working fine. The video is saved on the device.

I do need though, the name of the file that was saved.

I already can get this…

/private/var/mobile/Applications/D495AC17-F672-4D61-BBEB-7AC92358E0FF/tmp/capture-T0x16e2c250.tmp.cknraL/capturedvideo.MOV

But I need the name saved.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    // Handle a movie capture
    if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge_retained CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo)
    {

        NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:
                                UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];


        if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath))
        {
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath,self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: From @Elkucho: comment to deleted answer: I get NULL for contextInfo and the same path for videoPath.

Answer (score 0):

include `AssetsLibrary.framework` and `#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>`

Inside your `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method, you can do the following:

```
NSURL *imageURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetsLibrary assetForURL:imageURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
    ALAssetRepresentation *assetRep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
    NSLog(@"Image filename: %@", [assetRep filename]);
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

Comment: Hmm... can you post the output of `NSLog(@"%@", imageURL);`

Comment: can you please give the new solution since AssetsLibrary.framework is now deprecated